# can not assign any weights at the vertex group

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, vertex-groups, vertex-weights, vertex-paint

[image]

The shoe string didn't work(First image), but The shoe worked(Second image)
What should I do fix the error?

[image]

Comment: hello, maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I uploaded the file Thank you

Comment: hello, you need to share the link   ;)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T8T1ssOHeD4Bexpr5YSbFmslgxhQ28sl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: may be it worked

Comment: mmh weird because it worked for me for the first shoe, so I hope someone else will find out what's your problem

Comment: Thank you for caring I will keep trying to find a solution